# Validating form when directive creates form inputs dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to validate form while using directive. The directive creates form inputs by compiling and replacing the element.

If I use simple template version of directive it works fine. If the input created by directive is invalid form is also invalid. It even works when created in a loop as well : http://codepen.io/kuasha/pen/gbreKP

```
 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="myform" ng-submit="sendForm()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <myinput />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button ng-show="myform.$valid" type="submit">Submit!</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The app and controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sendForm = function () {
        if ($scope.myform.$valid) {
            alert('form valid');
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the simple working version of the directive:

```
app.directive('myinput', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<label>Test</label><input ng-model="value" type="text" required ng-minlength="5" />'
        };
    });
```

But if I change the directive to use a link function and compile then, even when the input inside the directive is invalid, forms $valid is still true: http://codepen.io/kuasha/pen/qEZoKv?editors=101

```
app.directive('myinput', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',    
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                var template = '<div><input type="text" required ng-minlength=5 /></div>'                               
                var newElement = angular.element(template);
                $compile(newElement)(scope);
                element.replaceWith(newElement);
            }                     

    };
});
```

Edit:

Directive could create its own validator-

```
app.directive('myinput', function ($compile) {
    return {
        require:'^form',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
        },      
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope){

        }],
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {
                var template = '<label>Test</label><input name="myctrl" ng-model="value" type="text" required ng-minlength="5" />'                               
                var newElement = angular.element(template);
                $compile(newElement)(scope);
                element.replaceWith(newElement);

                scope.$watch("value", function(){
                  ctrl.$setValidity('myctrl', scope.value && scope.value.length > 0);
                  console.log("Validity set");
                });                        
            }                     

    };
});
```

But its probably not right approach for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should switch the `replaceWith` and `$compile` ([**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/mgwer/pen/WbwzmE)):

```
element.replaceWith(newElement);
$compile(newElement)(scope);
```

I think it is because you can't really compile an element that is not yet in the DOM. But I'm not sure.